# Why should the variables be positive in the inequality condition?

Tags: inequality

I need to prove this statement:

> If $a,b,c > 0, then $ $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 \geq bc + ca + ab$

My attempt was:

Use the fact that $(a-b)^2 \geq 0 \iff a^2 +b^2 \geq 2ab$. Use this repeatedly with $(a-b)^2, (a-c)^2, (b-c)^2$ an adding up the rhs of each binomial and the lhs of each binomial gives

$2(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) \geq 2(ab + bc + ac)$ and hence proved.

but I never used the fact that a, b, c were positive. So is necessary that $a,b,c > 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion that the assumption is unnecessary is correct. Just look at what happens if one, two or three of the inputs is negative.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary.Your answer works